# working with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am working with Ajax this is the first time I am learning about it. I have a few questions if anyone would be nice to explains. I am working on something for my class he gave us this to use

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax Examples</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
font-family:      Trebuchet MS;
color:            #173F5F;
  background-color:#BFFFFF; 
 margin:10px;
 }
.formtable{
 border:2px solid #009999;
 background-color:#006B6b;
 color:#FF6600;
   }
.btnSubmit{
color:#FF6600;
background-color:#BFFFFF;
border:2px inset #FF6600; 
width:100px;
  }
h1{
color:#FF6600;
 }
input, textarea{
color:#FF6600;
border:1px solid #FF6600;
  }
hr{
background-color:#FF6600;
height:3px;
  }
#results{
color:#FF6600; 
width:300px;
 }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadurl(dest) { 
try {
    // Moz supports XMLHttpRequest. IE uses ActiveX.  
    // browser detection is bad. object detection works for any browser 
     xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():
     new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
}
catch (e) { 
    //browser doesn't support
    alert("Get with the times man!"); 
}
 // the xmlhttp object triggers an event everytime the status changes 
 // triggered() function handles the events
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = triggered;
 // open takes in the HTTP method and url. 
 xmlhttp.open("GET", dest);
  // send the request. if this is a POST request we would have  
  // sent post variables: send("name=valerie&gender=female)  
  // Moz is fine with just send(); but   
  // IE expects a value here, hence we do send(null);
 xmlhttp.send(null);
  }
function triggered() {
 // if the readyState code is 4 (Completed)  
 // and http status is 200 (OK) we go ahead and get the responseText   
 // other readyState codes:  
 // 0=Uninitialised 1=Loading 2=Loaded 3=Interactive
if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
    // xmlhttp.responseText object contains the response. 
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 }
</script>
<title>LAB 14</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Simple Ajax</h1> 
<hr>
<p>This page will automatically load another file into page below.</p>

<a href="#" onClick="loadurl('info.html')" >click here to load another file</a>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now all he said is is for us to make your info.html page about you - you could make it a resume or something else of your choice. Now I have one that i did. My question would be I have a ftp server we are suppose to upload it to. Would i be able to see the page before its uploaded to see if it works or am I doing something or have something wrong on the page that is not correct.

Comment: Cause when i pull up the file it will not click the link over to show what i type.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running a web server on your local machine, this won't work. You see this part?

```
if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
```

That means that unless the JavaScript receives a ["200 OK"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success) status code from the server that is hosting the page, it won't ever process the part inside the `if()` block.

You can try this instead:

```
if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200 || (xmlhttp.status == 0 && document.location.protocol == "file:"))) {
```

No guarantee this will work, but it should.

Comment: ok i understand that so once i upload it to my filzila i should be able to see it.. i am just having trouble logging into my school ftp..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing your code, it might be easiest just to install a simple webserver to test your code on.

For super simple stupid, I would recommend AnalogX's [SimpleServer](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/sswww/Freeware.htm) if you are on windows. It is really lightweight and does what you need.